# Upgrading Titanium Android Module from 1.7.5 to 1.8.0.1

Tags: titanium, titanium-modules

I already created a Titanium Android module for C2DM Push notifications in Titanium version 1.7.5. Recently I have upgraded my Titanium studio to 1.8.0.1, when I try to run the module I created, the build quits by saying following error message

```
[DEBUG] Looking for Titanium Module id: com.xxx.yyyy.zzzz, version: 0.1, platform: android
[DEBUG] module_id = com.xxx.yyyy.zzzz
[ERROR] The 'apiversion' for 'com.xxx.yyyy.zzzz' in the module manifest is not a valid value.  Please use a version of the module that has an 'apiversion' value of 2 or greater set in it's manifest file
```

=================

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got worked on Android.

```
apiversion: 2
```

to be added on the manifest file. For further more reference check this [URL](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Android+Module+Porting+Guide+for+1.8.0.1).